# When implementing a for loop in Javascript and using an increment. Would there ever be a time to decrement for one loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I was working through the exercises with the Odin Project and one of the tasks was to create a function that would remove specific elements from an array and return the new array without the specified elements. I created the following code which works, but seems very incorrect. Is there ever a time when something like this would be appropriate, or should I always look to do it a more elegant way.

```
const removeFromArray = function(myArray, ...elements) {
    for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        if (elements.includes(myArray[i])){
            myArray.splice(i,1);
            i--; // Here is the part in question
        }
    }
    return myArray;
};
```

Without the decrement:

```
myArray = [1,2,3,4];
elements = [1,2,3,4];
result = [2,4]
expected = []
```

I know the result occurs due to the nature of the splice operation which removes the items at the specified indices and then shifts everything together so that there are no gaps.

I have since looked at the official solution provided and realize a more elegant way to do this is:

```
const removeFromArray = function (myArray, ...elements) {
  const newArray = [];
  myArray.forEach((item) => {
    if (!elements.includes(item)) {
      newArray.push(item);
    }
  });
  return newArray;
};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: `and return the new array`,  your not returning a new array, but mutating an existing one.

Comment: I'd say it is preferred to write code where you don't have to undo anything, and to avoid working with index if possible. But if you have to, and particularly if you get better code than from avoiding it, go for it.

Comment: Your question is not related to a technical problem but a subjective one, so you may want to post it to [CodeReview.StackExchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Code is working as indented, right ?

Comment: @MoritzRingler Thank you. This is where I was wanting this question to go. It didn't feel like good practice to implement it the way I originally did, but your comment gave clarity as to why it didn't feel right.

Comment: @Keith Thank you for pointing this out. Yes, it is an important distinction to make, and one I should pay attention to in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this could be

```
let myArray = [1,2,3,4];
let elements = [1,2,3,4];

const removeFromArray=(myArray,elements)=>{
  return myArray.filter(item=>!elements.includes(item))
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw a little bit about .filter when I was trying to figure out how to solve this problem, but this is a very clear explanation.